# given absolute function, find the point where slope=1

Tags: derivatives

$y=|x^2-1|$ where $dy/dx=1$

- $dy/dx=2x$ when $y=x^2-1$
- $dy/dx=-2x$ when $y=-(x^2-1)$

I managed to find two point after splitting the function into two pieces, but my given answer only accept $(-1/2,3/4)$ while not $(1/2,-3/4)$
any explaination for this? as I do not understand

Comment: What is "given answer"?

Comment: (-1/2,3/4) only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point $(1/2,-3/4)$ is not on the curve, so there is no tangent there.  At $x=1/2, y=3/4$ and the slope of the tangent is $-1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\left|x^{2}-1\right|=\begin{cases}
x^{2}-1 & \text{if }x\geq1\text{ or }x\leq-1;\\
1-x^{2} & \text{if }x<1\text{ or }x>-1.
\end{cases}
$$
The derivative is
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left|x^{2}-1\right|=\begin{cases}
2x & \text{if }x>1\text{ or }x<-1;\\
-2x & \text{if }x<1\text{ or }x>-1.
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the derivative is undefined at $x=\pm1$. Moreover, note that $\pm 2x=1$ at $x=\pm 1/2$. However, only one of these two points is a solution. Can you figure out which one and why? It might help to [plot of the derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BAbs%5Bx%5E2-1%5D,x%5D).